# php reverse half pyramid numbers (special)

Tags: php, algorithm

How do i display php numbers like so?

```
     1
    21
   321
  4321
 54321
654321
```

right now my code is like this and displays the following.

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {

for ($j = 5; $j > $i; $j--)
{ echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;";

}
for ($l = 0; $l < $j; $l++){

}

for ($k = 1; $k <= $l; $k++) {
    echo "$k";
}
echo "</br>";
}
```

Basically this shows the correct way of the pattern but does not the correct numbers in order.

```
     1
    12
   123
  1234
 12345
```

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: you want to print like this  1 12 123 or 1 21 321.

Answer (score 2):

The code seems to have too many loops, and can use `str_repeat` to simplify the logic and loop structure. The counter was dependent on another loop, and thus couldn't be easily changed. I have refactored it into the following:

```
$printOut = "";
$count = 5;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
  $printOut = $i . $printOut;
  echo str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $count - $i) . $printOut;
  echo "</br>";
}
```

Output:

```
    1
   21
  321
 4321
54321
```